# SwiftUI: In a function, I'd like to instantiate AVAudioPlayer and play it

Tags: swiftui

If a button is tapped, I'd like it to play sound.

In "playSound" function below I'd like to instantiate AVAudioPlayer and play the sound but Xcode outputted `Exception caught in AudioQueueInternalNotifyRunning - error -66671` error and cannot play the sound.
A hoge.mp3 is already imported.

If I instantiate AVAudioPlayer out of the function, it successes but I would like to instantiate it in the function.

Do you have any solution?

Thank you.

```
func playSound(title:String){
        let tmpSound = try! AVAudioPlayer(data:NSDataAsset(name:title)!.data)
        tmpSound.play()
    }

Button(action: {
 playSound(soundName: "hoge")
 }){
 Text("Play".font(.title)
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this, works for me:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            playSound(title: "hoge")
        }) {
            Text("Play").font(.title)
        }
    }
    
    func playSound(title: String) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: title, withExtension: "mp3") {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                audioPlayer?.play()
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
      
}
```

EDIT-1: you can also do this if your mp3 files are in the Assets directory:

```
func playSound(title: String) {
    if let audio = NSDataAsset(name: title) {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audio.data)
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print("--> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this does not work for me on my simulator or on my device. I copied your code and wrote print(title) in do{} block but nothing was printed.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: yes, you have to (right mouse click, on the left panel in Xcode) `Add Files to ...`
 and select the `hoge.mp3`, so that it is part of your project.  If `print(title)` in `do{}` block shows nothing, it means you do not have the `hoge.mp3`
 in your project.

Comment: Thank you. That was right, I did not add them to my project. Now it works! By the way, do you know why my first code, `let tmpSound = try! AVAudioPlayer(data:NSDataAsset(name:title)!.data)`, did not work? I added my mp3 files to Assets.xcassets.

Comment: Maybe I found a reason. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92672. The variable "goes away" quickly after tmpSound.play() runs so if I add sleep(), it plays.

Comment: updated my answer with another way of using your Assets files.